# CAS proxyCallbackURL XML Response

Tags: java, cas

I am having trouble retrieving the XML response after the proxyValidate/ticket call to the CAS server. Everything is getting validated alright and the call back url is being called with the proper PGT and PGTIOU **BUT** since the application is distributed among different servers, i need to map the PGTIOU to the back-end in order for another server to be able to retrieve it.

This, obviously would be trivial if I can get a hold to the XML response from a successful proxyValidate (or seviceValidate) which includes the user and PGTIOU as per specified in the protocol for CAS 2.0+

My configuration is the following:

```html
<!-- begin CAS servlet filter --> 
  <filter> 
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>org.sakaiproject.login.filter.SakaiCasAuthenticationFilter</filter-class> 

        <init-param> 
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name> 
            <param-value>https://cas.someplace.edu/login</param-value> 
        </init-param> 

        <init-param> 
            <param-name>serverName</param-name> 
            <param-value>https://${serverName}</param-value> 
        </init-param> 
    </filter> 

    <filter> 
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class> 

        <init-param> 
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name> 
            <param-value>https://cas.someplace.edu</param-value> 
        </init-param> 

  <init-param>
       <param-name>proxyCallbackUrl</param-name>
       <param-value>https://test-sakai.someplace.edu/sakai-login-tool/pgtHandler</param-value>
     </init-param>

        <init-param> 
            <param-name>serverName</param-name> 
            <param-value>https://${serverName}</param-value> 
        </init-param>
        
    </filter> 

    <filter> 
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class> 
    </filter> 

    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/container</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping> 

    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
```

Where will I be able to receive the successful XML response? the validation is done by Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter but can't seem to be able to access it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter` has an internal cache for the (PGTIOU, PGT), which is by default in memory: https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client/blob/master/cas-client-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/client/validation/Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter.java#L78 For a distributed application, you should provide your own distributed cache.

The mechanisms is the following:

Client Authenticates -> CAS sends PGTIOU/PGT back via specified callbackURL
                     -> CAS answers the original request back and proxy/service validation filter process it, and attempts to retrieve the potentially stored PGT with the PGTIOU within the XML body.

For all this to work, the proxyCallbackUrl and proxyGrantingTicketStorageClass must be defined in the xml/spring configuration.

Comment: In my opinion, the mechanism on how the call back url works in conjunction with the storage implementation is vague, to say the least. However, looking through the code I was able to understand to complete my implementation joining the successful authentication and the callback PGT, with the PGTIOU as the glue, on the back end. My environment is really complex to get ecache to work for such a trivial task.